# Return lines where a number after a string match is less than a specific number

Tags: notepad++, numeric

I am using Notepad++ to filter a logfile.

The file contains lines like the two lines below this:

Line 1671: OUT product_one 9.4 5 pcl d0123456 "ip=10.21.79.146" 1 **74** 0 1d74f 1d74f e98 "" "" "" 01/10 00:08:07.0000  "x86_w4 6.2" "" 0 0

Line 1674: IN 1 product_one 9.4 pcl d0987654 "ip=10.21.79.53" 1 **73** 0 2a51a 01/10 00:08:42.0000

The IP addresses are ficticious.
The numbers in bold are the ones I am interested in. 
I want to mark lines where this number is less than 120. I can then remove these lines in Notepad++

Need to match any number **after** the string [" 1 ] (ignore square brackets). i.e. double quote space 1 space.
Then need to do the comparison where the number is < 120.
The numbers will never be higher than 999.

Comment: Note that you can write "less than 120" with a regex, it's `(1[01]|[1-9])?[0-9]`.  That matches all one and two digit numbers and only those three digit numbers starting with 10 or 11

Comment: Following on from Bens comment
    `\"ip=(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\"\s1\s(1[01]|[1-9])?[0-9]\s`
This is slightly stricter if you wish to make sure you are looking positionally at the right number.

Comment: Thanks Ben/Aidan. Using Ben's syntax, I can identify the rows using Search > Mark in Notepad++ and then remove them. Appreciate the help.